# Updating object values in JavaScript via function

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript I am trying to update an object value through a function, through which I am passing the object property to update.

However, this won't work - and I can see why, but don't know how to combat it!

```
myObject = {"testItem": "testValue"};
console.log(myObject.testItem);

function updateSomeValue(objectItem, newValue){
    myObject.objectItem = newValue;
}

updateSomeValue('testItem', 'newValue');
console.log(myObject.testItem);
```

Now, I can see the issue here is that in the function, myObject.objectItem is expecting an item in the object called objectItem - it won't translate it to testItem.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 6):

By using a different notation. Using `[ .. ]` you can specify the property name as a string.

```
function updateSomeValue(objectItem, newValue){
    myObject[objectItem] = newValue;
}
```